# How to do web searches in text-only web browsers

Tags: internet, browser, web

I usually use google but whenever I load it in a text browser I have to press down several times to go to the field where you enter the search string. This is redundant. How do people use text-only web browsers to do web searches?

Answer (score 3):

For most search engines, you can just modify the URL, append `?q=<term>` and do the search. E.g. -

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hello

https://www.google.com/search?q=hello

http://www.bing.com/search?q=hello
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Bibhas answer (try searching with eg `links www.duckduckgo.com` :/ ).

Surfraw can automatize that. It provides a fast unix command line interface to a variety of popular WWW search engines and other artifacts of power:

Surfraw uses your prefered text or graphical browser to display the result. This can be customized via `~/.surfraw.conf` (XDG's supported: `~/.config/surfraw/conf`):

```
SURFRAW_graphical_browser=/usr/bin/Firefox
SURFRAW_text_browser=/usr/bin/links
SURFRAW_graphical=no
```

An then,

- Search DDG for "foo":

  ```
  $ sr duckduckgo foo
  ```
- See Stackexchange's latest unanswered questions:

  ```
  $ sr stack -sort=null
  ```

Where *duckduckgo* and *stack* are Elvi [Full list of Elvi](http://surfraw.alioth.debian.org/#elvilist), just like DDG *bangs!*

Comment: tuk0z - when run in `gnome-terminal`, I can't get `surfraw` to recognize `~/.config/surfraw/conf`, but when I copy that conf to `~/.surfraw.conf`, it works fine - even though that second file is not even mentioned in `man surfraw`.  I'm not sure what XDG's are.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Well, I found their new home on gitlab, and in their [config documentation](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw/-/wikis/Configuration) I don't see any mention of `~/.config/surfraw/conf`.  I'll have to look more, but it *appears* that their `man` page is out of date.